# Proof of random variable using definition

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Let

$$X_{(1)} = \min(X_1,X_2,X_3), \qquad X_{(3)} = \max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$$

and $X_{(2)}$ the intermediate value.

Let $t > 0 $ and $Z_t$ be the number of indices $i$ such that $X_i \le t$. Prove that $Z_t$ is a r.v. Find the law of $Z_t$.

I'm thinking to use the definition to prove this.. a r.v. is $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\{\omega : X(\omega) \le t\} \in \mathcal{A}$ and it is defined on a probability space $\{\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P\}$.

Intuitively it is simple to think that $Z_t$ depends on another random variable and so it is a random variable, but how to prove this formally? Also which is $\mathcal{A}$ in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $Z_t$ can only take the values $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$ hence it suffices to show that $\{Z_t=i\}$ is measurable for each $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. To see this, note that $Z_t=0$ if and only if $X_i>t$ for each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ hence $\{Z_t=0\}$ can be expressed as an intersection of three measurable sets.

If you already know that $X_{(i)}$ are random variables, then $\{Z_t=i\}=\{X_{(i)}\leqslant t\}\cap \{X_{(i+1)}>t\}$, $i=1,2$ and $\{Z_t=3\}=\{X_{(3)}\leqslant t\}$.

If the previous fact is not know, write $\{Z_t=1\}$ as the union of the sets $\{X_1\leqslant t\}\cap \{X_2\gt t\}\cap \{X_3\gt t\}$, $\{X_2\leqslant t\}\cap \{X_3\gt t\}\cap \{X_1\gt t\}$ and  $\{X_3\leqslant t\}\cap \{X_1\gt t\}\cap \{X_1\gt t\}$ and use a similar idea for $\{Z_t=2\}$.